# Is it possible to stop the execution of a script temporarily on macOS?

Tags: macos, battery, python

I have a Python script that learns a Deep Learning model. It takes so much time to execute (usually more than 6 hours).

Now, the problem is it is MacBook Pro and I frequently go out with it, and sometimes cafes lack outlets. In such cases the Mac is going to run out just in 90 minutes even from 100% battery, as the Python program uses all the resources available.

I would rather like to stop or at least restrict the program while I'm on cafes without charging the laptop, and later make it start learning again. Is this possible in macOS? I use High Sierra.

Comment: This is not an Apple issue, but one of Python.   The question is, how do you pause a Python script - and that's technically off topic.

Comment: @Allan I agree it should be managed in Python but it takes too much work to implement it in Python, so I want to know if it is possible to control in OS-levels.

Comment: @Allan I agree it should be managed in Python but it takes too much work to implement it in Python, so I want to know if it is possible to control in OS-levels.

Comment: It’s not about Python, is about stopping/pausing a process, which is indeed possible sending the SIGTSTP signal

Comment: I was initially considering posting on Unix.SE, but for some reasons I ended up here. It should be better served there, and I'm 100% fine with the question being migrated. Sorry for the bad question...

Comment: @Blaszard - Not a bad question at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If executed from the shell you can type

```
CTRL + Z
```

this will send the "terminal stop" signal (SIGTSTP) to the process and the system  won't schedule any more CPU time to the process.

You can then restart it by typing

```
fg
```

on the same shell.